# Changing text color in edit box of android according to the focus

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using the below xml file to change the color of editbox. But i would like to know how to change the text color in the editbox according to the focus. If the editbox is focussed i like to change the text color to black and when it is not focussed i like to change the color to white.

How do i implement this in the xml file? Any help would be really useful for me in learning the android drawable resources.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <selector
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_focused="true">
    <shape>
        <gradient
            android:endColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:startColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:angle="90" />
        <stroke
            android:width="3dp"
            android:color="#0f0f0f" />
        <corners
            android:radius="10dp" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:state_focused="false">        
    <shape>
        <gradient
            android:endColor="#000000"
            android:startColor="#000000"
            android:angle="90" />
        <stroke
            android:width="3dp"
            android:color="#151515" />
        <corners
            android:radius="10dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

Comment: Sorry xml file was not copied properly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should use [ColorStateList](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/ColorStateList.html) instead of State List.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#ffff0000" /> <!-- pressed -->
<item android:state_focused="true" android:color="#ff0000ff" /> <!-- focused -->
<item android:color="#ff000000" /> <!-- default -->
```

then just assign this state list to textColor property.

Comment: Thanks :D !! I was able to change the text color. After assigning the statelist to textColor property.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for a [State List](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList).

Comment: Hi Gary, Yes I am looking for State List which is used to change the edit text color. I tried using android:textColor inside the item tag but i am not getting the results i expected.